# Should I think about linked list returned by getaddrinfo when I get addrinfo for my "home" server

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2, getaddrinfo, getaddrinfo-a

I created a server using sockets that runs on my home network. `socket address=192.168.88.123:7777`
When I call getaddrinfo() function I put "192.168.88.123" as first parameter and "7777" as second and also some hints (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) and pointer to the result linked list. I noticed that in this case I always get linked list with only one structure.

**Question:** should I think about linked list in such case (when I am working over my own server) or getaddrinfo will always return linked list with one element?

Comment: If it returns you a list, then you'll have to take care about it. **Now** if you are sure that your request will always return a single element, then take the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `getaddrinfo()` is to get a list of IPs.

If you request a specific IP address as input, the resulting list will contain only 1 element for that same IP.

If you request a hostname as input, the resulting list will contain an element for every IP that the hostname resolves to.

If you don't request an IP/hostname at all, the resulting list will depend on whether the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is used. If the flag is used, the list will contain elements for `0.0.0.0` and/or `::0`, depending on the `ai_family` requested.  If the flag is not used, then the list will contain elements for `127.0.0.1` and/or `::1`, depending on the `ai_family` requested.